# Hadoop Multi Output maintaining record order emitted from map

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am trying to achieve Multiple Output from the reducer in hadoop. The files are created properly, the problem is the header and footer of the file does not comes in proper places(i..e, the ordering of the records that are emitted from the map are changed).I am having one mapper and multiple reducers.

I tried to add an index(like an integer) to each map records and remove it from the reducer keys, but it was giving as file already exists exception. I was using a custom comparator to sort the keys based on the index values.

Any ideas on what am i missing.

Comment: Are you processing your headers and footers using custom InputFormat with RecordReader ? If yes then are you using the headers/footers information outside the RecordReader means at you mapper ?

Comment: Hi Stacey,
Thanks for the reply. I was processing the header and footers inside the RecordReader and using the information later while generating the file back using Multi Outputs.
I have resolved the issue and also solved the too many open files handlers issue.